# Error in plot.window(...) : se necesitan valores finitos de 'xlim' ERROR EN RSTUDIO

Tags: r, rstudio, recursión

En un trabajo de la universidad, me salio este error en: #Valor estimado
Y = 0.3366 + (1.2520*datos[,1]) + (-0.6581*datos[,2]), desde ahi.

Primero tenia mi tabla en xlsl, de excel, y luego la volvi a guardar como csv, pero no corri el programa hasta que tuviera la tabla en csv. Importe la tabla, todo corria bien las primeras lineas.

```
#Problema: Realizar estudio de credito


#Experiencia:Comportamiento financiero de clientes
datos <- read.csv("dat_clientes.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE)


#Encontrar modelo lineal (lineal model)
fit = lm(decision ~ ingresos + gastos, data=datos)

#Medida de desempe?o del modelo
summary(fit)


#Valor estimado
Y = 0.3366 + (1.2520*datos[,1]) + (-0.6581*datos[,2])

#windows()
plot(datos[,1],datos[,2],col=round(Y)+1)
lines(datos[,1],round(Y), type="l")

#nuevo cliente
nuevo = 0.3366 + (1.2520*0.5) + (-0.6581*0.8)
points(0.5,0.8, pch=2,col=3)
round(nuevo)
```

El resultado es este:

Terminal:

```
> #Experiencia:Comportamiento financiero de clientes
> datos <- read.csv("dat_clientes.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE)
> #Encontrar modelo lineal (lineal model)
> fit = lm(decision ~ ingresos + gastos, data=datos)
```

"Primeras dos lineas de codigo. En la tercera summary, ya me salen la informacion y al final esto."

```
Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 199 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

"Y en valor estimado ya comienza el error."

```
> #Valor estimado
> Y = 0.3366 + (1.2520*datos[,1]) + (-0.6581*datos[,2])
Error in 1.252 * datos[, 1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

```
> #windows()
> plot(datos[,1],datos[,2],col=round(Y)+1)
Error in plot.window(...) : se necesitan valores finitos de 'xlim'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

"La ultima sentencia".

> #nuevo cliente
> nuevo = 0.3366 + (1.2520*0.5) + (-0.6581*0.8)

Comment: Tienes un problema con los datos importados, revisa si son realmente numéricos: `sapply(datos, is.numeric)`